# Integrando o FormFlow com o LUIS da Microsoft

Tags: microsoft, chatbot, luis, bot-framework

Fiz um bot utilizando o SDK BotBuilder da Microsoft. Quero que um FormFlow do BotBuilder reconheça e capture entidades em uma resposta do usuário. Por exemplo, se o usuário responder: meu e-mail é jose@gmail.com, então o FormFlow teria que capturar, como resposta para a pergunta dele apenas o email (jose@gmail.com), ignorando a parte inicial do texto(meu e-mail é). É possível fazer isso apenas com FormFlow ou é preciso utilizar o LUIS para fazer isso? Como que o LUIS pode ser utilizado juntamente com o FormFlow?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível.

Na hora de construir seu FormFlow, para todas as propriedades da sua entidade, configure o método Field() do formflow com o parametro validate e chame um método que tente extrair todas as entidades possíveis do LUIS e guarde na instancia que o FormFlow está preenchendo.

```
 .Field(nameof(NomePropriedade), validate: async (state, value) => await ExtractEntity((state as NomeClasse), value, "nomeEntidadeLuisCorrespondenteAoCampoDaVez"))
```

aplicando ficaria assim:

```
     .Field(nameof(DataNascimento), validate: async (state, value) => await ExtractEntity((state as Cliente), value, "data_nascimento"))
```

assim em cada pergunta que o FormFlow faz vc pode interceptar e extrair as entidades do luis e mandar pro state.

O método ExtractEntity ficaria assim:

```
 protected static async Task<ValidateResult> ExtractEntity(Cliente state, object value, string entityName, Func<ValidateResult, Task<ValidateResult>> next = null)
    {
        INLPService service = NLPServiceFactory.Create("NomeServicoLuis");
        var nlpresult = await service.QueryAsync(value.ToString());
        var entity = nlpresult.QueryEntity(entityName);
        var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity) ? value : entity };

        var nomeEntity = nlpresult.QueryEntity("nome");
        var dataNascimentoEntity = nlpresult.QueryEntity("data_nascimento");

        state.Nome = CoalesceEntityValue(nomeEntity, entityName, "nome", value.ToString(), state.Nome);
        state.DataNascimento = CoalesceEntityValue(dataNascimentoEntity, entityName, "data_nascimento", value.ToString(), state.DataNascimento);


        if (next != null)
            return await next(result);
        else
            return result;
    }
```

E por fim o método CoalesceEntityValue decide qual valor atribuir na propriedade, o valor extraido do luis, o que usuário digitou ou o valor atual.

```
 private static string CoalesceEntityValue(string extractedEntityValue, string extractedEntityName, string entityName, string rawEntityValue, string currentValue)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extractedEntityValue))
        {
            return extractedEntityValue;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawEntityValue) && entityName == extractedEntityName)
        {
            return rawEntityValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return currentValue;
        }
    }
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.